# Where can I locate two M8 brake posts for a 1995 Cannondale Head Shock Fork

Tags: brakes

I use these brake posts on two different 80's - 90s Cannondale mountain bike to mount Shimano V-Brakes and Magura hydraulic rim brakes. The end that threads into the fork is M8. Most brake posts these days are M10, and the supply of M8 brake posts seems to have dried up.

Comment: What part of the ones you have failed?

Comment: Maybe check to see if you have a bike co-op in your area. The one in my city is a treasure trove of older parts.

Comment: All else fails an engineering shop could easily cut down the M10mm post to  M8

Comment: I recently bought several titanium M8 VBrake posts for not too much money on eBay, new.

Comment: @NathanKnutson I did not have a brake post fail. I accidentally threw them out. ):

Comment: @Kibbee That is an excellent suggestion. Unfortunately, Covid has not been kind to the coop in my town.

Comment: @mattnz That is a good idea!

Comment: @BetterSense Yes, I see that there are M8's available in Asia. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Vintage cannondale

https://shop.vintagecannondale.com/

Please update question if you actually need the imperial 5/16" size.